# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'nivoSlider'

Tags: jquery, slider, nivo-slider

I am getting an error for nivoslider, when I debug it in chrome I found this `no method nivoSlider` The code was workin fine until I added another slider contentslider. Now its just showing the last image and not moving. I heard aboutt this topic so came to conclude like if you use 2 sliders with jQuery it creates conflicts or something like that, I don't know help please.

```
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
        <?php $banner_query=executeQuery("select * from tbl_picture where status=1");
            while($banner=mysql_fetch_array($banner_query)){?>
        <img src="image/<?php echo $banner['picture'];?>"  alt="<?php echo $banner['title'];?>" title="<?php echo $banner['title'];?>" border="0"/>
        <?php }?>      
    </div>  

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="codelibrary/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="codelibrary/js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#slider').nivoSlider();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use 2 or more sliders with the same ID selector you will likely run into conflict. However currently it appears that you are using it stock out of the box in concept, with the exception of the use of PHP rolling out the slides. There's very little to go on generally speaking though in this scenario to know exactly whats going on.

If you can post some code somewhere where myself and others like me can go view it and see for ourself we may be able to better assit, however currently based on your question it and the mention of wanting to use more than one at a time, my conclusion is that your likely using the same ID `#slider` for both sliders on the page you want to have them on.

Answer (score 0):

This error is telling you that the JQuery object (`$('#slider')` in this case) has not a nivoSlider method, that means nivoSlider plugin has not been loaded for some reason.

With every probability one of this things is happening:

- You have not included jquery **before** including nivoSlider
- You are including **more** than once the jquery source

This has nothing to do with how many sliders you have in your page, this is a script loading issue. 
Obviously, if you have more than one, you must not use the same ID.